# Access iCloud Drive using javascript/jquery API

Tags: jquery, cloud, storage

I'm working on a SPA html5/jquery application where the user needs to be able to pick files from various cloud storage providers. I have successfully integrated Google Drive, OneDrive and DropBox.

Now I wonder if it is possible to to the same against iCloud Drive or if it is mandatory to connect from Apple device using proprietary languages?

I would love to get som pointers if it is possible.

Also, the above, working integrations all work of IE11, Chrome, Firefox and Safari but NOT IE Edge! After authenticating to the cloud storage provider, nothing more happens on Edge, it seems to loose itself not knowing the caller. Dropbox displays a message saying unable to communicate with parent window. Has anyone been able to make these services work in Edge? Is there some security settings realted to scripting etc that can be tweaked in Edge (haven't found any).

Thanks,

Kind regards
Hans

Comment: Did you find the solution on your own?  Can you please share it?